# C# remove cache while is being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Imagine I have 100 custom objects in cache, each object is a company and has a number associated.

Company 1: 763, Company 2: 603, Company 3: 829...

I calculate an average number with these numbers, and also cache the average.

While users are navigating the website, all there numbers and the average is in ASP.net cache.

Now in the background I have a process that updates from time to time these numbers to the database.

Then I iterate through the cache and delete all the companies objects and also the average cache, something like this:

```
foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in HttpRuntime.Cache)
{
   HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove((string)entry.Key);
}
```

The question is: how can I be sure that in the middle of removing all these items from the cache, the average is not being miscalculated in the frontend website? (remember I also save the average in cache)

For example, suppose the website is loaded again while cache from company 53 is being removed (and the rest up to 100 pending delete). So in one time the average could be miscalculated with old and new numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear in terms of who can recache and how that relates to the front end website, but when caching, you have to assume that at some point _you will either experience a cache miss_ OR _you will retrieve stale data from cache_.  Which is the greater offender depends on your scenario.

Comment: Caches are self-maintaining.  There's no guarantee that what you put in the cache will be there when you go to fetch it (what @DavidL describes as a _cache miss_).  I strongly suggest that you use something whose lifetime you manage more directly for this.  When you say *"in the background I have a process that updates..."*, I'm assuming you don't mean *Process* (i.e., another process outside your app pool).

Comment: @DavidL thanks! I share the cache between the frontend website and the backend. In the frontend code, I load from cache, if there is a cache miss it loads from the database. When I update in the backend method, I delete all the cache and the info is loaded again into the cache in the backend too.

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks! I meant method, no process! :)

Comment: @delavega it still isn't clear how you are calculating averages during cache rebuilds.  Are you using the cached data to compute the average?

Comment: @DavidL yes, I use first the cached data when available, if they are null I retrieve data again from database. The average is being calculated iterating a collection of these companies objects. When finished, I also cache the average, which I'm not sure if it would be correct, because the new average could be recalculated with old cached numbers in case the average cache is deleted first than the companies objects. Thanks!